# How do I debug HTTP of Ruby google-api-client

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, faraday

I'm trying to integrate with Google Drive, using the google-api-client. Since there's a lot of stuff going on, I would like to be able to see what's going over the wire (http level). It seems that the client uses Faraday for http connectivity. How would I get a wiredump out of Faraday for debugging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google api client uses `Faraday.default_connection` by default. It is thus possible to manipulate this object, which can be done simply with the following line of code:

```
Faraday.default_connection.response :logger
```

Took me a while to figure out.

Comment: Hey thre. I'm having some trouble with a request to the google-drive API and I tried using this solution to inspect the http traffic, but it seems to not be working... Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Just a wild guess - you might have to set the logging level of whatever logger it is that Faraday uses. And obviously look in the logs.

Comment: Oddly, I only got this to log the first response (the OAuth one), not the actual API request.

Comment: @jwadsack It might be - and mind that I'm merely guessing here - that they use Faraday for authentication, but then switch to something else thereafter?

Comment: The `result.response` object I get back (with all the API data) is a `Faraday::Response` object, so they are using Faraday. I'm not sure what was causing that, but I'm beyond it anyway.