# 503 (Service Unavailable) when trying to Create File to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

We've been getting a 503 error since yesterday when making this call:

```
result = session.execute(
  api_method: drive.files.insert,
  body_object: file,
  media: media,
  parameters: {'uploadType' => 'multipart', 'alt' => 'json'}
  )
```

We have 3 set of keys - one each for our development, staging, and production environments.

The above call works without issue in our development environment, but fails 100% of the time in both staging and production environments

Comment: What does the response message say?

Comment: one of the affected devs here. The message is blank.

Comment: Does each environment have its own API project, or do they share the same one? I take it these are on 3 different URLs?

Comment: yes. all under different project/keys. All well under traffic limits.

Comment: same code deployed in staging/production

Comment: and the code that talks to GDrive is the same in dev too

Comment: Details about the file? Mime type? Also, does your staging/production environment go through any proxies that might be modifying the request in any way?

Comment: All transfers from production and staging are failing.
here is a small sampling of mime types:

    `image/jpeg 
    application/pdf 
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

No proxies.

Comment: also of note.. we get the 503 when either creating a file or updating an exiting file `drive.files.insert`, `drive.files.update`. No problems getting an access token

Comment: One of the affected devs here. This is not related to our keys, we've tried our production keys on our dev machines and it works fine. 503 is 100% when running on our staging or production servers, both of which are ubuntu 12.04 on AWS EC2. Any ideas how to further debug, we're 100% down on production trying to upload files to GDrive?

Comment: It has to be something about the environment - either headers getting rewritten or injected in some way that is breaking the upload. Or something wrong with reading the file. Did you change anything in your production environments recently? FYI, you can inject a connection instance from Faraday into the API requests. Might help to build a connection with logging middleware enabled to capture the full http request/response.

Comment: thanks for replying. we're checking the environments again

Comment: Hey Steve, any examples out there doing this? `you can inject a connection instance from Faraday into the API requests`

Comment: were you referring to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900195/how-do-i-debug-http-of-google-api-client

Comment: Steve, I have a gist containing the traffic flow up to the 503 error. Don't really want to post the link here though. Contact me at support@openera.com - Use "SO Bug" in the subject. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the gists shared privately, it looks like the issue is the user agent header. I was able to reproduce by setting the UA similar to that one. I haven't been able to narrow it down to a particular issue with the UA, just that it doesn't work. Other multi-line strings work, and other chars seem fine if I replace the newlines.

Anyway, easiest thing to do is set :application_name with a different value that what you're using now.

Comment: in consideration of future api users who might have this issue, would it be possible for the server to include a "Bad User-Agent" message in the 5XX response?

Comment: in case anyone is wondering what was wrong with our User-Agent.. newline characters