# Google Drive API returning 403 when trying to download file - no information about error given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

So, I have a ruby on rails project, I'm using the google-api gem and I'm trying to download a file from an account that I previously gave permission to my project to access and manage my google drive files. I have the refresh token and the access token and for some time, the download works fine. For some reason, after the access_token expires, even after I request a new one from the API using the refresh (which does work), the download request returns a 403 error with no information whatsoever about what 403 error it is.

First: why, after refreshing the access_token, am I still getting the 403 error?
Second: why is the response not returning any information about the error?

Fyi, if I go to my account, de-authorize the app and then authorize it again through my app, the download works fine again.

I really need help, since this kinda breaks my whole project if it doesn't work.

Edit: Tried again to see if the problem was still happening. I deleted my account yesterday, gave permission again to manage files and it worked until the access_token expired. After that it gives the 403 error message, even after using the refresh token to update the access one. Below is what I get from client.execute (with the client key and secret edited):

> Response from Google API: #"16653014193614665626", "e"=>"download", "gd"=>"true"}, @headers={"User-Agent"=>"google-api-ruby-client/0.7.1 Linux/3.13.0-24-generic\n (gzip)", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Content-Type"=>""}, @api_method=nil, @authenticated=nil, @authorization=#https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth>, @token_credential_uri=#https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token>, @expiry=60, @extension_parameters={}, @additional_parameters={}, @client_id="***.apps.googleusercontent.com", @client_secret="***", @scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"], @access_token="***", @refresh_token="***">, @body="", @http_method=:get, @uri=#>, @response=# @request=# @request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"google-api-ruby-client/0.7.1 Linux/3.13.0-24-generic\n (gzip)", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Content-Type"=>"", "Authorization"=>"Bearer ***", "Cache-Control"=>"no-store"} @ssl=# @response_headers={"access-control-allow-origin"=>"*", "access-control-allow-credentials"=>"false", "access-control-allow-headers"=>"Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Type, Date, GData-Version, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Origin, OriginToken, Pragma, Range, Slug, Transfer-Encoding, X-ClientDetails, X-GData-Client, X-GData-Key, X-Goog-AuthUser, X-Goog-PageId, X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable, X-Goog-Correlation-Id, X-Goog-Request-Info, X-Goog-Experiments, x-goog-iam-role, x-goog-iam-authorization-token, X-Goog-Spatula, X-Goog-Upload-Command, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Disposition, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-File-Name, X-Goog-Upload-Offset, X-Goog-Upload-Protocol, X-Goog-Visitor-Id, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-JavaScript-User-Agent, X-Pan-Versionid, X-Origin, X-Referer, X-Upload-Content-Length, X-Upload-Content-Type, X-Use-HTTP-Status-Code-Override, X-YouTube-VVT, X-YouTube-Page-CL, X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp", "access-control-allow-methods"=>"GET,OPTIONS", "date"=>"Wed, 20 Aug 2014 13:13:22 GMT", "expires"=>"Wed, 20 Aug 2014 13:13:22 GMT", "cache-control"=>"private, max-age=0", "server"=>"UploadServer (\"Built on Aug 12 2014 13:30:28 (1407875428)\")", "content-length"=>"0", "content-type"=>"text/html; charset=UTF-8", "alternate-protocol"=>"443:quic", "connection"=>"close"} @status=403>>>

After analysing the response while looking for things to hide (like the access_token), is it possible that the "access-control-allow-methods" paramater having the date and expires date the same is the issue here?

Comment: Trace the http traffic and you will see additional information regarding the 403. While you are at it, double check that your http requests do indeed contain an access token as from memory, one possible cause of a 403 is a missing access token.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that if the traffic is all encrypted? I'm looking at the traffic on wireshark and I can't seem to find where the 403 is.

Comment: you need to enable logging in the SDK library. I don't use rails, so can't be more specific, but I'll have a google for you and post a comment if I find it.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900195/how-do-i-debug-http-of-google-api-client

Comment: Thanks for finding it, but I can't make it work. I put the line of code on the function that actually makes the connection and the first time I used it I got a middleware error of some sorts. I moved the line of code to the previous method and the error stopped, but there is nothing on the console or in any of the logs. :(

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/FAQ ?

Comment: That worked. :) Sad thing though: it shows the same thing as the response I posted above, after editing. Nothing more. =\ I am really at a loss here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59660/discussion-between-sidner-and-pinoyyid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the downloadUrl is directly connected to the access token. By storing the downloadUrl with the first access to the file's metadata and using the same downloadUrl with a new access token, the API was returning a 403 error. By requesting a new downloadUrl everytime a new token is requested as well, it works perfectly.

Comment: This will usually affect non-native files. The latest guidelines for downloading content is here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error means that you don't have the required rights, in this case, you are trying to use an expired token, this sounds like you have a problem with your cookie policy, change your cookie policy to none and let us know if the problem goes away.

Happy coding

Comment: I am absolutely sure the token sent on the header is the new one and not the expired one. Besises, the error for an expired token is 401 not 403. Nevertheless, I will try your proposed solution...although I'm not sure how to do it. Can you help there, please? Thank you.

Comment: Didn't forgot about you, just had to look more in depth at your case =)

Here I found someone who found a bug in the Access_Token of you client, it seems you should use a slightly older version.

https://github.com/google/signet/pull/31

And here he made an article detailing how he pulled it off, it should fit your project:

http://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2013/12/17/how-to-access-your-google-drive-files-with-ruby/

I'm sure the code it's right, but as I mentioned earlier, bug happens, please let us know if this help you, worst case I'll share your plea with other GDE's.

Happy coding